# Would direct use of kinetic energy be able to simulate a solid object?

Tags: science-based, magic, physics

For context, imagine that a human being has reality warping powers based on knowledge. Basically, if you know how something works and what manipulations have to happen for a certain result to occur, you can make it happen.

The question then is, if you can give kinetic energy to anything, such as air, would you be able to, for example, somehow manipulate the direction of that energy in such a way that it would be able to create a kinetic construct that is solid to the touch even if it's in thin air or basically any material safe for a solid one.

The energy for it can be supplied continuously and in vast amounts.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Thank you. Going a bit off the topic-if the kinetic energy could somehow be applied without a medium such as air in reaction to for example, an object of certain density reaching a certain point in relation to the person using the power, would that be able to simulate solidity?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE Alex.  I removed the [tag:reality-check] tag from your question because [tag:science-based] supersedes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if by direct use of kinetic energy this includes the kinetic energy inherent in the thermal motion of, for example, air itself, then the answer is yes.

Since your hypothetical human being can warp reality it should be a straightforward for him or her to warp reality in such a way that it is full of [Maxwell's demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon). The until now purely hypothetical demons will be able to direct individual atoms to move in aligned directions.

Effectively there will be a flow of kinetic energy aligned in a set of directions that would correspond to the shape of a solid object. At the edges of the 'object' there will be demons whose task it is randomize the motions of the atoms of air. Thereby, restricting manifest 'solid object' to within a given volume.

Demon-manipulated volume of air will behave like a negative pressure and act to exclude people and objects from entering the volume of the 'solid object'. This is the equivalent of the way solid objects prevent other matter from penetrating the space they occupy. The negative pressure only has t be strong enough to behave as if it was a solid.

In conclusion, reality warping powers can bring into exostence maxwell's demons in sufficient numbers to manipulate the kinetic energy associated with their constituent atoms of tenuous forms of matter like air or even fluids like water to behave as if they were solid objects.

Comment: Thank you very much a4android! This is the answer I was hoping for, including the context. It also answers questions I haven't asked, like how cryomancer and pyromancer-like effects would be achieved. Much appreciated. Wish I could upvote but don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: There was a superhero, in Marvel comics I believe, that could create solid holograms made from sound. Sounds a lot like the question.

Answer (score 4):

Ever stood against a strong wind? You can lay off the vertical and not fall down, like something solid is holding you.

Ever been knocked down by a wind gust? Ever got your umbrella broken by a sudden blow of wind under the rain?

That's exactly what you are asking for, and it doesn't need magic at all. Some even made a business out of it, with inside skydive facilities, where you float against a strong up-flow of air.

Comment: Yes, I assume then that just a strong enough gust of wind would do the trick, but that not exactly what I mean. To make it feel solid, would you just need to confine it to a certain space? And if so, would you use rotational energy confined to a small scale or direct energy that is just limited to a certain distance. Sorry if I'm not wording it properly, to say my knowledge of physics is not the best would be an understatement, specific terms even more.

Comment: Or if the power allows kinetic energy to be applied without a medium such as air, would that work? Like for example, if an object of some kind reaches some point in relation to the user of the power and has kinetic energy applied to it in responce in such a way that it doesn't just lauch said object back, would that work? Thank you.

Comment: @AlexPetricov, sorry, we are not a forum where you ask A, get an answer and then develop a thread of discussion on the answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm new to the site. Could you direct me to the forum where discussions continue in threads? Thanks for your attention.